# What translation does the Catholic Breviary of England use for Psalms?

Tags: catholicism, prayer, psalms, liturgy-of-the-hours

I've heard that in England the Roman Catholic Liturgy of the Hours uses a different translation for the readings from the U. S. (Specifically, the British use Jerusalem Bible in their liturgies (including Mass) and the U. S. uses the N. A. B.) I have not been able to confirm, however, whether they use the Grail Psalms for their Liturgy of the Hours. Do they use a different Psalter?

Comment: Note that the Ordinariate of Our Lady of Walsingham uses the Revised Standard Version (2nd Catholic Edition) for readings at Mass. The Ordinariate's Breviary has not yet been published.

Comment: I hope they use the RSV for their breviary. I'll buy a copy if they do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, I just looked on amazon.co.uk to find the Divine Office published by Harper Collins for the use in the United Kingdom, New Zealand, Australia, etc...  Didn't have a preview or anything, but I did [find this](http://www.adoremus.org/499DivineOffice.html) which says:

> Psalms are from the 1963 version of the Grail Psalter.

Comment: Yes: this is correct!

Comment: And unfortunate. The Jerusalem Bible's Psalter is a FAR superior translation.

Comment: @AndrewLeach if you've got anything to add to the answer go ahead, I should have waited to let you answer since you've probably got 1st hand experience.

Comment: I don't think there's anything else to add! The answer's right; I can bear your research out from experience. I didn't intend to muscle in, although some expansion of the OP's implication of *all* England needed clarification (again from experience).